# Xampp - Help! Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp

Had a Problem when trying to run Mysql on XAMPP, the error shows

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums
```

When checking the mysql error log its shows like this

```
2020-03-07 09:11:44 1918 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2020-03-07  9:11:44 6424 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2020-03-07  9:11:44 6424 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2020-03-07  9:11:44 6424 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2020-03-07  9:11:44 6424 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-03-07  9:11:44 6424 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2020-03-07  9:11:44 6424 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2020-03-07  9:11:44 6424 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2020-03-07  9:11:44 6424 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2020-03-07  9:11:44 6424 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-03-07  9:11:44 6424 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring page 0 of tablespace 0
2020-03-07  9:11:44 6424 [Warning] InnoDB: Doublewrite does not have page_no=0 of space: 0
2020-03-07  9:11:44 6424 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
2020-03-07  9:11:44 6424 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2020-03-07  9:11:44 6424 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2020-03-07  9:11:44 6424 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2020-03-07  9:11:44 6424 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-03-07  9:11:44 6424 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2020-03-07  9:11:44 6424 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2020-03-07  9:11:44 6424 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Any solutions how to fix this crash?

Answer (score 0):

does it fresh install or modified because the error show `you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was`

Comment: not a fresh install, but I dont event remember edit innodb_data_file_path

Comment: have you run MySQL successfully before, if not have you install the MySQL as service?